# How to Join 3 MYSQL Tables with multiple conditions and even if no data in 3rd table

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join, outer-join, join

My New Project is something like a blog roll in which users can follow other users.

While listing all Posts, There will be a button to follow/unfollow under each post.

Tables used are users, posts and followers. which are as follows:

**USER Table**

```
id       firstName     lastName
.....................................
1        arun          prasanth
2        ann           antony
3        sruthy        abc
6        John          abc
```

**POSTS Table**

```
id    user_id   postname    url
.....................................................
1     2         post1       www.url1.com
2     2         post2       www.url2.com
3     6         post3       www.url3.com
4     3         post4       www.url4.com
```

**Followers Table**

```
id     user_id    following_users_id    date
..............................................
1     2          1                     2018-01-25
2     2          3                     2018-01-25
3     6          3                     2018-01-25
4     3          6                     2018-01-25
```

to list all posts my query was like:

```
SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN users on posts.user_id = users.user_id;
```

and it worked fine as both table have corresponding rows and the result was by listing both table columns with all data.

Now My issue is while joining third table, ie followers table. problem with followers table is, it will have only one row which corresponds to current logged in users user_id and followers.user_id.

i tried all variants like LEFT RIGHT INNER and OUTER JOIN's. but no success.

the result i want is:

```
user.id                         -> xxx
user.firstName                  -> xxx
user.lastName                   -> xxx
posts.id                        -> xxx
posts.user_id                   -> xxx
posts.postname                  -> xxx
posts.url                       -> xxx
followers.id                    -> xxx
followers.user_id               -> **Logged IN Users ID**
followers.following_users_id    -> **posts.user_id**
followers.date                  -> xxx
```

the followers.id, followers.user_id, followers.following_users_id, followers.date should be printed only if **followers.user_id === Logged IN Users ID** AND **followers.following_users_id === posts.user_id** is true. else those columns should be blank.

Is there any way i can retrieve data as mentioned above of should i use something like a foreach loop?

Comment: Please show the query that you have tried.

Comment: It's unclear what you want from the query. Posts and Followers appear to be two different things, unless you want to see all the followers of the post from a particular user but even then you'll need to group things so I'm not sure what it is you expect. I suspect you need multiple queries for specific output in code but I can't tell for sure. Post your desired output from the database

Comment: @GordonLinoff : 

"SELECT * FROM posts JOIN user ON posts.user_id = user.id JOIN followers ON  posts.user_id = followers_user_id AND followers.following_users_id = $_SESSION['user_id']"

Comment: @Cfreak: i need to get all posts table data along with user table data. and want to join followers table if **followers.user_id === Logged IN Users ID** AND **followers.following_users_id === posts.user_id**

Comment: @compulsivecoder You can `LEFT JOIN` the followers but it's going to duplicate your rows.

Comment: @Cfreak: yeah thats the problem. i only have 240 posts. but the result retrieve almost 600+ records by duplicating. the followers.id, followers.user_id, followers.following_users_id, followers.date should be printed only if followers.user_id === Logged IN Users ID AND followers.following_users_id === posts.user_id is true. else those coloumns should be blank

Any Idea How???

Comment: There are some tricks you can do to concat data from a subquery but I don't think that's the best design. It would be better to get unrelated data separately in separate queries.

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks for your Suggestion :)

Comment: can you update the question and add in a ascii (text) formatted data table with the results you expect based on the example data.. instead off `user.id                         -> xxx user.firstName -> xxx` and so on..

Comment: Please setup a https://www.db-fiddle.com/ with some relevant and minimal sample data. Please go through this link once: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)